# Менять цвет фона при наведении и уведении курсора JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Написал спокойно вариант, когда меняется фон при наведении.

> $("tr").mouseover(function() {
>       $(this).css("background-color", "lightblue");
>   });

Не могу разобраться, как объединить 2 события, чтобы при уведении курсора цвет фона возвращался прошлый.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<style>
.tr-over {
  background-color: "lightblue";
}
</style>

$("tr").mouseover(function() { $(this).addClass("tr-over"); });
$("tr").mouseout(function() { $(this).removeClass("tr-over"); });
```

Comment: Благодарю !!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Вот так подойдет?

```
$('tr').bind({
'mouseover':function() { $(this).css("background-color", "lightblue"); },
'mouseout':function() { $(this).css("background-color", "darkblue"); },
});
```

Comment: Не подошло, так как у разных tr разные цвета же могут быть.

Comment: а поподробнее насчет разных цветов можно?

Comment: @cyadvert, в вашем случае при mouseout - всем строкам будет устанавливаться один цвет, а не возвращаться тот который был изначально

Comment: Да, мне нужен изначальный цвет. Ответ выше мне полностью подошёл.